# Kerbtray realm and kdc for java gss-api

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, jdbcrealm, gssapi

I'm using kerbtray.exe on Win7.

How do I know exactly what the realm and kdc is for a java gss-api login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably referring to the krb5.ini maintenance, right? You should start with the realm your process is logged in to. If you plan to do cross-realm, you have to add every realm which you want to authenticate to and eventually your root realm. If you are unsure, you can look it up with DNS:

```
$host -t SRV _kerberos._tcp.<you realm>
```

and

```
$host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.<you realm>
```

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx) for reference.

Comment: How exactly do you propose I look that up?

Comment: Ok - so I've said this is Win7 - and you're proposing linux. Are you suggesting I use cygwin on Windows? What makes you think I shouldn't use kerbtray on win7?

Comment: You should then ask your admin instead for some KDC servers. This is what you will need for the krb5.ini.

Comment: If I didn't have an existing KDC, then I wouldn't have entries in my kerbtray output. Surely the point of kerbtray is so that I don't need to ask the administrator. Where are you going with this?

Comment: Kerberos in Java works different than Windows does. Java uses GSSAPI where as Windows uses SSPI. Java simply requires the krb5.ini just list Unix does. Period. If don't provide some, you are out of luck.